# Are integrated networking devices, frequently called routers, of the switch type or of a router / NIC type?

Tags: switch, router, ethernet, cable

**Odom,*Wendell*-_CCNA_200-301_Official_Cert_Guide,_Volume_1.pdf** :

> many SOHO Ethernet LANs today combine the router and switch into a single device. Vendors sell consumer-grade
> **integrated networking devices** that work as a router and Ethernet switch, as well as doing
> other functions. These devices typically have “router” on the packaging, but many models
> also have four-port or eight-port Ethernet LAN switch ports built in to the device.

When choosing between straight-through and cross-over cables should I treat those integrated networking devices frequently called routers as of the same type as PC's NIC (or router) or of the type of switch?

I am aware that the presence [auto-mdix](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/stand-alone/ethernet-wiring/#auto_mdix) in such devices may diminish the importance of the cable choice. But let this be outside of the scope of the question.

Comment: I don't think i've ever seen a home/small buisiness router that didn't have auto-mdix, nor do I think i've seen one that explicitly said whether the ports were MDI or MDI-x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The devices that that quote seems to talk about are the ubiquitous (and off-topic here) integrated "routers" or "modems" that often include

- WAN PHY (DSL/cable modem)
- router with NAT for IPv4
- small switch (multiple LAN ports)
- DHCP and DNS server
- rudimentary firewall
- SIP gateway for VoIP telephony
- NAS/multimedia server (less common)

> When choosing between straight-through and cross-over cables should I treat those integrated networking devices frequently called routers as of the same type as PC's NIC (or router) or of the type of switch?

That is a good question - even with just a single LAN port, most of those consumer-grade devices use MDI-X as pinout (hub/switch-type) for better host connectivity. Routers without an integrated switch use MDI ports (host/NIC/router-type) for better switch connectivity.

Of course, the majority of modern devices support Auto MDI-X, so the distinction has become much less important than a few decades back.

Comment: Even enterprise grade gear often contain switches -- Cisco ESM is a full IOS running switch on a blade, and the WIC-[4,9]ESW is a 4/9 port basic switch on a WIC. (just to name two)

Comment: @Ricky Agreed - I've softened that a bit, to not complicate things too much.